# Solr/Lucene : Is it possible to overload a method in a Custom Similarity Class?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

Is there some file where I can change the arguments that are passed to the similarity class, to decide which version of the overloaded method will be used?

I can't find the answer in online documentation.

Comment: what is your solr version?

Comment: @stephanruhl Solr 4.9.0!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The similarity section to the end of the schema file if where you can specify a custom similarity or use another Similarity apart from the which comes bundled with Solr.

This is whats present under the default schema.xml -

```
  <!-- Similarity is the scoring routine for each document vs. a query.
   A custom Similarity or SimilarityFactory may be specified here, but 
   the default is fine for most applications.  
   For more info: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Similarity
-->
  <!--
     <similarity class="com.example.solr.CustomSimilarityFactory">
       <str name="paramkey">param value</str>
     </similarity>
    -->
```